# How to replicate use/import literal argument handling for a subroutine?

Tags: perl

The behaviour I'm after is documented in Perldoc for `Exporter`. It lists three cases for importing based on not only the number of arguments but if arguments were specified at all:

> use YourModule;
>
> This imports all the symbols from YourModule's @EXPORT into the namespace of the use statement.
>
> use YourModule ();
>
> import any symbols.
>
> use YourModule qw(...);
>
> This imports only the symbols listed by the caller into their
> namespace.

How do I write a sub which knows if literal arguments are specified AND if so how many?

This is easy to do with variables as a reference to an array can be used and dereferenced in the sub, or if `undef` considered as no arguments provided:

```
sub my_sub(){

  if(@_ and ref $arg eq "ARRAY"){
    # Argument provided and is an array
    # Count them, could be zero
    my $arg=shift;
    my $count=$arg->@*;
    
  }
  else{
    # No argument or not an array ref
  }
  
}
```

However it’s the literal values I want to work with and I can’t get to work as the `Exporter` description above. I’ve played with the prototype `;+@` which sort of works. However a literal list passed in is only available in scalar context and has to be within a extra level of `()`. This gives `undef` for an empty list, but also only gives the last element in the list to the subroutine:

```
sub test :prototype(;+@){
 say $_ for @_
}
```

Calling as `test()` or `test` prints nothing, indicated that the `@_` is empty.

Calling as `test(())` prints an empty line, indicated an undef value.

Calling as `test((10,12,13))` prints 13 only. Scalar context on list?

Calling as `test(1,2,3)` or `test 1,2,3` prints the numbers one to a line.

How can I tell if the subroutine is called with no literal arguments `test` and literal (possibly empty list) `test ()` and also handle normal `test ('arg',...)` and still have access the arguments?

Comment: "_called with no literal arguments `test` and literal (possibly empty list) `test ()` and also handle normal `test ('arg',...)` and still have access the argument_" --  I don't get this at all :(.  What do you mean by "_literal_" (arguments)?  String literals as opposed to variables?  (Why would that matter?)  How do you expect `test` and `test()` to differ and why is `test('arg'...)` "_normal_"?

Comment: Instead of `my @var=(10,11); test @var;` literal would be `test(10,11);`

Comment: OK, thanks.  So to be able to tell `t(7)` or `t(1,2)` or `t()` vs `t($v)` and/or `t(@ary)`

Comment: Basically I want to know if a literal list (even if its empty) has or has not been passed to a subroutine: ie in the same fashion `use MODULE ();` is different to `use MODULE;`

Comment: Re "*Scalar context on list?*", Yes, scalar context on comma ("list") operator.

Comment: May I ask ... why do you need to know whether it was `t(3)` (or `t($x)` I guess), etc?  Why there were string literals. There may be some other way to answer the questions behind that, what you really need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A sub can't tell whether it called as `foo()`, `foo`, or `foo( LIST )` where `LIST` produced zero scalars.

At least, not without peeking at the internals. For example, if the sub can obtain the opcode of the call site (which may or may not be possible), it could examine the surrounding opcodes to see if `()`, nothing at all, or something else was used.<sup>[1]</sup>

Or the module that contains the sub could install an opcode checker that literally modifies the opcodes of the call to pass an extra argument indicating which form was used.

These are extreme measures, and best avoided in favour of a better API. `use`'s special behaviour for `()` and `qw()` is a source of headaches, not something that should be duplicated.

---

So what's happening in the case of `use Foo ();` vs `use Foo;`?

| Code | Equivalent |
| --- | --- |
| `use Foo;` | `BEGIN { require Foo; Foo->import(); }` |
| `use Foo qw( abc def );` | `BEGIN { require Foo; Foo->import(qw( abc def )); }` |
| `use Foo @a;` | `BEGIN { require Foo; Foo->import( @a ); }` |
| `use Foo ( );` | `BEGIN { require Foo; }` |
| `use Foo qw( );` | `BEGIN { require Foo; }` |

You assumed that `Exporter::import` could tell if `()` was used or not, but that's not the case. `Exporter::import` doesn't export anything when `()` is used because `import` is not called at all in that situation!

The difference is based on how the compiler parses `use` statements, not some check performed by `Exporter::import`.

---

1. ```
    $ perl -MO=Concise -e'sub foo; foo()'
    6  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
    1     <0> enter v ->2
    2     <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{ ->3
    5     <1> entersub[t1] vKS/TARG ->6
    -        <1> ex-list K ->5
    3           <0> pushmark s ->4
    -           <1> ex-rv2cv sK/1 ->-
    4              <#> gv[*foo] s ->5
    -e syntax OK

    $ perl -MO=Concise -e'sub foo; foo'
    6  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
    1     <0> enter v ->2
    2     <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{ ->3
    5     <1> entersub[t2] vKS/TARG ->6
    -        <1> ex-list K ->5
    3           <0> pushmark s ->4
    -           <1> ex-rv2cv sK/NO(),CONST,1 ->-   <-- "NO()"
    4              <#> gv[*foo] s ->5
    -e syntax OK

    $ perl -MO=Concise -e'sub foo; foo( @a )'
    8  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC ->(end)
    1     <0> enter v ->2
    2     <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{ ->3
    7     <1> entersub[t4] vKS/TARG ->8
    -        <1> ex-list K ->7
    3           <0> pushmark s ->4
    5           <1> rv2av[t1] lKM/1 ->6            <-- Extra code
    4              <#> gv[*a] s ->5
    -           <1> ex-rv2cv sK/1 ->-
    6              <#> gv[*foo] s ->7
    -e syntax OK
   ```

Comment: haven't been here for a long time but I could tell this was one of your generous and high quality responses before I scrolled own far enough to see your name.  Great as always. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

I don't get why you start the question with quoting `Exporter`, but

> How do I write a sub which knows if literal arguments are specified AND if so how many?

Literals are readonly and `@_` holds aliases which will be readonly too.

Scalar::Util is core and provides a routine [readonly](https://perldoc.perl.org/Scalar::Util#readonly)

```
use v5.12.0;
use warnings;
use Scalar::Util qw(readonly);

sub test{
    for my $idx (0..$#_) {
        print "Arg $idx = $_[$idx] is ";
        print "NOT " unless readonly $_[$idx];
        say "readonly";
    }
}



use constant c=>4;
my $x   = 2;
my $ref = \5;


test( 1, $x, 3, c, $$ref );
```

--->

```
Arg 0 = 1 is readonly
Arg 1 = 2 is NOT readonly
Arg 2 = 3 is readonly
Arg 3 = 4 is readonly
Arg 4 = 5 is readonly
```

NB: not only literals can be readonly, some symbols like constants are too.

But I think this should be in fact still what you want.

###### === update

expanded examples with more readonly cases.

---

###### UPDATE

You seem to want to access the literal source of arguments used in the call, there are only hacky backdoors to access that even the suggestion by Ikegami to parse the Optree won't cover all edge cases caused by optimizations.

And since `caller` will only give you the line and not the character position of the call, having the original source will still imply parsing Perl code.

But if this is just about differentiating `foo();` vs `foo;` you could help yourself with `&foo();` vs `&foo;`and checking `$hasargs = (caller)[4]`

Without knowing more I can't suggest a solution, this still smells a lot like an XY Problem.

Comment: The `Exporter` quote is to highlight the fact that there is a difference between `use`/importing with no arguments and importing with an empty argument list. It's how to detect this difference I would like to figure out and if it is possible to apply to a general subroutine. ie  `test` vs `test ()` or even `test(())`. I'm assuming this syntax is special to a `use` statement at the moment.

Comment: AFAIK is Exporter implemented in Perl, so you can take a look there. I suppose `use` is setting a magic flag.

Comment: FWIW: `Carp::cluck()` can distinguish between `&test()`  and `&test` but only when called with leading ampersand, I suppose this is done with `(caller)[4]` hasargs.

This looks a lot like a XY Problem, I'll leave it to you to follow those leads.

Comment: `&test()` disables the prototype check, and does give a different list of arguments. `&test` reuses the argument array which is what the `(caller)[4]` ($hasargs) indicates (false on reuse?).  I'll look into that some more.

Comment: ikegami is right `use MODULE ()` will never call `->import` , that's documented in [use](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/use) and easily tested to be true. I'll update my answer